# graph theory " three nodes of degree 0 1 3 respectively"

Tags: graph-theory

Does this graph exist

" 3 nodes of degree 0 1 3 respectively"

i don't think so because if you have a degree of zero it would be disconnected from the other 2 nodes and on that premise you cannot have 3 degrees with 2 nodes, but could someone please help me confirm or deny this.

Comment: Are you allowed a loop which connects a node to itself?

Comment: If your graph isn't simple, consider a graph on three vertices $u,v,w$ where $u$ is connected to itself and $v$. $u$ has degree 3, $v$ has degree 1, and $w$ has degree 0.

Comment: this makes sense, i didn't think of it like that. thanks =D

Answer (score 1):

No if we only consider simple graphs, yes otherwise.

**Simple Graph Case:**

If one of the nodes has degree three, that means it is connected to **three other nodes** by edges. So the graph must have at least four nodes.

But we know it only has three. So it's impossible for the graph to exist (because four is more than three).

**Non-Simple Graph Case:**

Consider a graph with three nodes $a,b,c$. Let $a$ have degree zero. Let $b$ share an edge with $c$. Add a loop on $b$ (an edge from $b$ to $b$).

Then $a$ has degree $0$, $b$ has degree $3$, and $c$ has degree $1$.

It's a useful fact that a node with a loop on it has degree $2$.

The proposition is also trivially true if we allow multigraphs (graphs with multiple edges between nodes).

Comment: Couldn't we cheat and have the node of degree $3$ have looping edge to itself?

Comment: @macpierce271 Yes, this is possible in certain contexts, but I assumed not in the context that the OP is asking for. (We could also cheat by permitting multiple edges between nodes, etc.)

Comment: I disagree with your edit. Check my example in the comments to the question.

Comment: @JacopoNotarstefano You raise a good point. I was just thinking about it. What's the degree on a node with an edge to itself? Is it 1 or 2? Edit: it's 2. This changes things.

Comment: @JacopoNotarstefano I changed my answer.

Comment: Now I agree! I think this question boils down to "Is your graph simple?", a concept which the OP should understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider a graph with and edge that connects a node to itself. If you are not allowed to do this, then disregard this hint.